# Cannot get recipient message in live chat signalr

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, signalr

I do not appear to be able to extract the message from one user to another in signalR.  The code from the text box and the userfrom and userto is going to the server, but I do not be able to produce it into the chat box.  I've completely ran out of ideas.  I am trying to get users to communicate from two different pages, so not sure if that is the problem.

js:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    var chatHubProxy = $.connection.chat;

    chatHubProxy.client.recieveMessage = function (username, message) {

        alert(username, message);
        //writeToChat(username, message);
    }


    var writeToChat = function (username, message) {
        $('#chatConversation').append(
            '<div class="container border-bottom border-dark userChatbox">'
            + '<label>' + username + ': </label>'
            + '<p>' + message + '</p>'
            + '</div>'
        ).animate({ scrollTop: $('#chatConversation').prop("scrollHeight") }, 600);
    }

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

        function JoinChat(user, userType) {
            chatHubProxy.server.joinChat(user, userType);
        }

        $('#sendButton').click(function () {
            var GuardianName = $('#hdnGuardianUser').val();
            var UserName = $('#hdnChatName').val();
            var message = $('#txtMessage').val();
            if (GuardianName) {
                chatHubProxy.server.sendMessageToUser(GuardianName, message, UserName)
                    .done(writeToChat(GuardianName, message))
            }
        });

        $('#btnGoToChat').click(function () {
            var user = $('#txtChatName').val();
            JoinChat(user, 'User');
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var GuardianName = $('#hdnGuardianUser').val();
            JoinChat(GuardianName);
        });
    });
</script>
```

c#:

```
    public void JoinChat(string username, string userType)
    {
        users[username] = this.Context.ConnectionId;
        if(userType == "User")
        {
            SendMessage(username);
        }
        
    }

    public void SendMessageToUser(string userFrom, string message, string userTo)
    {
        if (users.ContainsKey(userTo))
        {
            this.Clients.Client(users[userTo]).receiveMessage(userFrom, message);
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not a SignalR expert, but it looks to me like your javascript for each client is starting a brand new hub; seems like you'd want to be connecting to a hub that the server had started.  Have you seen the SignalR example js?  https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/signalr/hubs/sample/wwwroot/js/chat.js

Comment: To test... change this.Clients.Client(users[userTo]). to this.Clients.All(). to send to every connected client. If that works, then I suspect that your users[userTo] value is not a valid connection id.

Comment: Hi I tried changing to this.Clients.All and still I dont get anything through. The chatboxes are in different views would that be the potential cause?

Comment: @Stu No, having different views should not be a problem as long as you have a connection and method to call in each. You may need to add some try/catch logic to find any exceptions that are occurring.